# Solving ODE: How do you go from $\frac {d x}{dt} = Ax$ to $\lambda x = Ax$ again?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a relationship

$\frac {d x}{dt} = Ax$, where $x = [x_1, x_2]$

I know that you are supposed to solve this by moving $Ax$ to the LHS forming

$\frac {d x}{dt} - Ax = 0$

But how do we go from this step to:

$(\lambda I - A)x = 0$ and then solve for $det(\lambda I - A) = 0$ to prove that there exists non-trivial solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you look for solutions of the form $$x = e^{\lambda t} u, u \neq 0,  \frac{dx}{dt} = \lambda e^{\lambda t} u $$ the constraint on $u$ and $\lambda$ is $Au = \lambda u$. now you are back to eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A.$

you use the fact that $A - \lambda I$ is singular iff $det (A - \lambda I) = 0$

Comment: Why can I assume $x$ is of this form?

Comment: @MathNewb You can actually rigorously prove that the solutions are of this form by first showing that $e^{At}v$ is a solution for a fixed vector $v$. It's not a very simple argument but it can be done. Then by considering the case when $v$ is an eigenvector, you get exactly what abel has.

Comment: the short answer is it works. in the  sense that if $u$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda,$ then $x = e^{\lambda t} u$ solves $\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax.$ this is just checking algebra. more fundamentally how do you come up with, i don't know.